# Problema certificado Amazon con Chrome

Tags: servidor, ssl, aws, certificado-ssl, ec2

Cree e instale un certificado Amazon en mi instancia ec2 siguiendo este procedimiento:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ouIWJchfFA

Pero Chrome me sigue marcando el sitio como "No es seguro". ¿Cual puede estar siendo el problema?. Gracias

Comment: al poner el domino, conecta por https? tal vez necesites una redirección del puerto 80 al puerto 443 (https) . esto se puede hacer en el virtualhost o en `.htaccess`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, parece que el problema era el chrome, fui a opciones=> restaurar chrome, y empezó a andar bien (mostrarme el sitio como seguro). Gracias!